# How can I add a YouTube embedded video to an image carousel? HTML / CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

I have a carousel for a product and it has 1 image and 1 video. The image shows up alright but when I try to press on the video so it pops up into main carousel view, it doesn't work. My index.html code (I omitted the actual video link from this source code) is:

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
    

    <div class="column">
        <img id=featured src="images/sample1.jpg">

        <div id="slide-wrapper" >
            

            <div id="slider">
                <img class="thumbnail active" src="images/sample1.jpg">
                <iframe class="thumbnail" width="560" height="315" src="videolink" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-2">
        <p>Home / Sample Item 1</p>
        <h1>Sample Item 1</h1>
        <h4>$00.00</h4>
        <h3>Product Details</h3><br>
        <p>Manufactured in CANADA</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

In the same source code I have a Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let thumbnails = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail')

    let activeImages = document.getElementsByClassName('active')

    for (var i=0; i < thumbnails.length; i++){

        thumbnails[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            console.log(activeImages)
            
            if (activeImages.length > 0){
                activeImages[0].classList.remove('active')
            }
            

            this.classList.add('active')
            document.getElementById('featured').src = this.src
        })
    }

</script>
```

My CSS code:

```
body{
    padding-top: 100px;
}

#content-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.column{
    width: 600px;
    padding: 10px;

}

#featured{
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 600px;
    object-fit: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid black;

}

.thumbnail{
    object-fit: cover;
    max-width: 180px;
    max-height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;

}

.thumbnail:hover{
    opacity:1;
}

.active{
    opacity: 1;
}

#slide-wrapper{
    max-width: 500px;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100px;
    align-items: center;
}

#slider{
    width: 440px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;

}

#slider::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 8px;

}

#slider::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

}
 
#slider::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #dede2e;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
   border-radius: 100px;

}

#slider::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
    background-color: #18b5ce;
}

.arrow{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s;
}

.arrow:hover{
    opacity: .5;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

When I hover over the image - the image works and I can see it, but when I hover over the little embedded video, it gives a broken image sign in the main carousel view (above the thumbnail). What am I doing wrong? How can I make the video show up normally when I hover over it?

Answer (score 0):

i have tried a bit of thing andgone thorough many thing and got this solution you can just change the css and place the
elements where you want to get your desired result.

1. html:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="ray-so-export.png">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cCYObFBEp0k" frameborder="0"
          allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="preview"></div>
    </div>
```

2. css:

```
    .container {
    display: flex;
    }
    
    .box {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .box:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .preview {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    }
    
    .box img,
    .box iframe,
    .preview img,
    .preview iframe {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    object-fit: cover;
    }
```

3. javascript:

```
    var box = document.querySelector('.box');
    var preview = document.querySelector('.preview');
    
    box.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    
    if (target.tagName === 'IMG' || target.tagName === 'IFRAME') {
    var clone = target.cloneNode(true);
    preview.innerHTML = '';
    preview.appendChild(clone);
    }
    });
    
    box.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    preview.innerHTML = '';
    });
```

you can also refer this [codepen](https://codepen.io/geekvinayak/pen/QWJwbop) of mine for the same.

do comment if anything else

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I'll be honest, this is my first time with coding so is there any way you can show me how to do that exactly with my code? Like what should I write and where?

Comment: @EmeraldBay now try the answer i have edited it